# D3 legend for line chart axes

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have line chart made with the help of d3.js which has axes showing numbers with units such as 0m, 1m 2m, 3m..etc for varios units. I want to show legend for these units such  m = mili, n=nano, B = billion etc near the line chart.

Comment: There are a lot resources searched on Google. I just picked on up for you. [d3-legend](http://d3-legend.susielu.com/) is one of [searched results](https://www.google.com.tw/search?q=legend++d3.js&oq=legend++d3.js&gs_l=serp.3..0i19j0i5i30i19l4j0i8i30i19l5.1280.3137.0.3261.7.7.0.0.0.0.130.377.4j1.5.0....0...1c.1.64.serp..2.5.374...0j0i3j0i30j0i5i30.Ta-ZJEr4K2k).

Answer (score 0):

Here is the an [example](http://bl.ocks.org/siddharthpolisiti/fce500057d7cf378cbbbb1718ea6a21c) of line chart with legends. I am not sure if you are following the same process to draw your line charts as most examples in d3 use the same. But as your question do not have any code so here goes an [example](http://bl.ocks.org/siddharthpolisiti/fce500057d7cf378cbbbb1718ea6a21c) anyways.Below is the snippet of how to do so:

```
var legend = svg.selectAll(".legend")
    .data(cities)
    .enter().append("g")
    .attr("class", "legend")
    .attr("transform", function(d, i) {
      return "translate(0," + i * 20 + ")";
    });

  legend.append("rect")
    .attr("x", width - 18)
    .attr("width", 18)
    .attr("height", 4)
    .style("fill", function(d) {
      return color(d);
    });

  legend.append("text")
    .attr("x", width - 24)
    .attr("y", 6)
    .attr("dy", ".35em")
    .style("text-anchor", "end")
    .text(function(d) {
      return d;
    });
```